# Js Convert Photo Cam in Input File

Tags: javascript

I have a webcam that is taking a photo, mediaDevices.getUserMedia, in local SrcObject, but I want the photo to go to an input type = file. how do i convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just programmatically put `File` object to `<input type="file">`

What you can do is create a `Blob` object out of captured screenshot and later on send it with rest of formdata.

```js
const getScreenshotFromCameraBlob = () => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const video = document.createElement('video');
  video.setAttribute("autoplay", true);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      video: true
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg');
      })
    })
    .catch(reject)
  )
}

getScreenshotFromCameraBlob()
  .then(blob => {
    console.log(blob);
    sendScreenshot(blob);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  
const sendScreenshot = (blob) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("screenshot", blob);

  fetch('', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
}
```